# Plotting an inverse linear regression fit curve in R and it doesn't look right

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm trying to fit some data point to an inverse linear regression curve. I want the curve to look like this:

[image]

However the following curve gives me a line that is almost straight up and down which doesn't make sense. I searched the internet for how to do this and there doesn't seem to be a lot of helpful stuff. I'd appreciate if anyone knows how to do this

```
x <- (1:75)
w <- rep(10,25)
z <- rep(5,25)
a <- rep(4,25)
b = append(w,z)
y = append(b,a)
model = lm(y ~ I(1/x))
plot(x,y)
abline(model)
```

Answer (score 4):

`abline()` plots a straight line while your function y= f(1/x) is not.  So What you need to do is use the `predict()` function like this:

```
x <- (1:75)
w <- rep(10,25)
z <- rep(5,25)
a <- rep(4,25)
y = c(w, z, a)
model = lm(y ~ I(1/x))
plot(x,y)


y2<- predict(model, data.frame(x))
lines(x, y2)
```